# How can I generate a FindBugs report that shows me the bugs removed between two revisions in the bug database?

Tags: findbugs

I am attempting to execute a combination of the FindBugs commands filterBugs and convertXmlToText, against a bug database that I created, to generate a report that shows me the all of the bugs removed between two revisions of the system that I am working on.  Unfortunately, the resulting report does not show any bug details.  It appears that the convertXmlToText throws away all bugs that are dead (aka inactive)... the exact set of bugs that I'd like to see.  Below is what I see when I pass the results of the filterBugs command to the mineBugHistory command:

```
build/findbugs/bin> ./filterBugs -before r39921 -absent r41558 -active:false ../../../mmfg/bugDB-2.xml | ./mineBugHistory
seq     version time    classes NCSS    added   newCode fixed   removed retained        dead    active
0       r39764  1271169398000   438     74069   0       64      0       0       0       0       64
1       r39921  1271186932000   441     74333   0       0       22      0       42      0       42
2       r40149  1271185876000   449     74636   0       0       3       0       39      22      39
3       r40344  1271180332000   452     74789   0       0       7       0       32      25      32
4       r40558  1271179612000   452     74806   0       0       1       0       31      32      31
5       r40793  1271178818000   464     75610   0       0       20      0       11      33      11
6       r41016  1271176154000   467     75712   0       0       4       0       7       53      7
7       r41303  1271175616000   481     76931   0       0       7       0       0       57      0
8       r41558  1271175026000   486     77793   0       0       0       0       0       64      0
```

What I'd like to see in the HTML report is the list of the 64 bugs that are shown as active in version r39764 (sequence # 0).  Below is the command line that I am using to generate the HTML report:

```
build/findbugs/bin> ./filterBugs -before r39921 -absent r41558 -active:false ../../../mmfg/bugDB-2.xml | ./convertXmlToText -html:fancy-hist.xsl > ../../../mmfg/bugDB-removed.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Try http://sonar.codehaus.org/